# Python Find Average in Nested Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, average, nested-loops

I was trying to do this using arrays, but my lack of any programming skills made that difficult. So here's to trying something else.

I have a program:

```
for x in range (0,N2):
    I=1 #resets the variables
    Q=0
    U=0
    for x in range (0,N):
        theta= 90+randint (-dtheta,dtheta) #random component 
        Q0=Q
        U0=U
        I0=I
        I=(I0*cosh(dTp)+S*sinh(dTp))*exp(-dT) #reuses P from previous run through
        Q=(Ip*cos(2*theta)+Q0)*exp(-dT)
        U=(Ip*sin(2*theta)+U0)*exp(-dT)
        P=100*sqrt(Q**2+U**2)/I
        print 'x=', x, 'P=', P
```

So, the program goes through the complicated equations to get a P-value, and loops through those equations `N` number of times. Then it changes some variables randomly, and goes through the process `N2` number of times.

What I am trying to do: every `N2` time it hits a `N` value, I want the average of those values.

This is what the program (printing `x` and `P`) currently prints.

```
x=0 P= 0.666656790299
x=1 P= 1.33305129414
x=2 P= 1.99135189726
x=3 P= 2.65356540458
x=4 P= 3.31718464722
x=5 P= 3.94383330744
x=6 P= 4.57470649236
x=7 P= 5.22041300059
x=8 P= 5.87783977662
x=9 P= 6.53297448834
x=0 P= 0.666656790299
x=1 P= 1.33244225853
x=2 P= 1.96631331155
x=3 P= 2.6285933052
x=4 P= 3.2901846442
x=5 P= 3.95565476517
x=6 P= 4.61500717059
x=7 P= 5.27548752021
x=8 P= 5.87881617052
x=9 P= 6.53895040683
```

where N2=2 and N=10. Do you see how there are two values like .66 (`x=0`)? And two like 6.5 (`x=9`)? I want to be able to have the average of all the numbers that have the same N value. So, the average of all the x=0 values (~.66) the x=1 values (~1.33) all the way to x=9 values (~6.65).

The end goal is to graph all these averages versus N.

Any help would be amazing, because I know next to nothing on programming.

Comment: Could you please provide a fuller code example of your code? You've left out the irrelevant stuff but also stuff that is needed to help you. Furthermore: a little bit of the background of what you're actually trying to compute might end up being useful.

Comment: It is not clear what numbers do you want to use for an average. Do you mean average of numbers being 0.66 and later average of numbers being 6.5? Or you mean number of the same values? Rephrase your question and try to replace words like "these" by good definition or term with clear meaning.

Comment: @user3576982 to expand on Erik's comment. At the top of your script on your computer you have import statements - could you add the relevant ones to the code in your question? Could you also add a few lines of code that define the variables you use in the loop? This way people who are trying to help you can run your code on their computers.

Comment: @user3576982: here's something to get you started with programming: http://learnpythonthehardway.org :)  (...and why not http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sums = [0] * N

for x in range (N2):
    I = 1 #resets the variables
    Q = 0
    U = 0
    for x in range (N):
        theta = 90 + randint(-dtheta, dtheta) #random component 
        #you don't need to copy these variables, they're redundant
        #Q0=Q
        #U0=U
        #I0=I

        #reuse the P-value from previous iteration
        I = (I * cosh(dTp) + S * sinh(dTp)) * exp(-dT)
        Q = (Ip * cos(2 * theta) + Q) * exp(-dT)
        U = (Ip * sin(2 * theta) + U) * exp(-dT)
        P = 100 * sqrt(Q**2 + U**2) / I
        print P

        #add the value of P to the corresponding index at x in sums[]
        sums[x] += P

#this is called a list comprehension
#it is a nicer way of looping over an iterable object (like a list)
avgs = [n / float(N2) for n in sums]
```

Comment: perhaps `sums = [0] * N; avgs = [x / float(N2) for x in sums]` .

Comment: @ErikAllik hehe, I just changed it to that right as you commented. :)

Comment: this looks like exactly what I want to do, but it's giving me a list index out of range error on the avgs[N]+=P line. Anyone know how to fix that? Thanks so much for getting me this far.

Comment: @user3576982: I think it's supposed to be `avgs[x]`.

Comment: Yes, it should be avgs[x]. As @ErikAllik suggested, I changed the variable name to `sums` though for the first part of it because it makes much more sense. So it's `sums[x]`. I left the last line as `avgs` so you have two lists, one of the sums and one of the averages. Also make sure you're including the `sums = [0] * N` before the loops begin.

Comment: Oh, my God. It worked. I have been working the whole week on this. You guys have absolutely no clue how grateful I am for your help. And Erick Allik, thanks for the links; I'll be sure to check them out. Jumping into the middle of Python was hard, it will be nice to start from the beginning. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad we could help! You should accept the answer since it helped you. :) Just click the green checkmark below the score on the left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure where in the loop you are requesting to average the value.

Put a counter variable outside of that.  Count the times you calculate P.  Then have a sum_p variable to maintains the total values of all P's calculated.

Then average is just sum_p/cnt.

When you want to start tracking a new average, you would set cnt = 0 and sum_p = 0.  We have cnt for free with N.

```
for x in range (0,N2):
    I=1 #resets the variables
    Q=0
    U=0
    sum_p = 0
    for x in range (0,N):
        theta= 90+randint (-dtheta,dtheta) #random component 
        Q0=Q
        U0=U
        I0=I
        I=(I0*cosh(dTp)+S*sinh(dTp))*exp(-dT) #reuses P from previous run through
        Q=(Ip*cos(2*theta)+Q0)*exp(-dT)
        U=(Ip*sin(2*theta)+U0)*exp(-dT)
        P=100*sqrt(Q**2+U**2)/I
        sum+p += P
        print P
    print 'Avg', sum_p//N
```

I'm not sure why you are creating a duplicate copy of Q,U,I.  Instead of just using the previous copy in the calculation.  This is perfectly valid, it uses the old value and sets the new value.

```
        I=(I*cosh(dTp)+S*sinh(dTp))*exp(-dT) #reuses P from previous run through
        Q=(Ip*cos(2*theta)+Q)*exp(-dT)
        U=(Ip*sin(2*theta)+U)*exp(-dT)
```